# C Parser repeating outputs unusually

Tags: c, parsing

Alright, bear with me because there's some weird stuff here.
I'm currently trying to implement a SUPER simple shell with max 20 char commands and no piping, etc. I'm also learning C along with it so please forgive any egregious errors or usage.

Here's my code for a parser:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int running = 1;

    /* Main loop */
    while(running==1) {
        // The max size of the input is 20 bytes
        char input[20];
        // Read string from user
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

        /* ----- PARSE INPUT ----- */
        char buffer[20];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++) {
            buffer[i] = input[i];
            /* ------ CHECK BUFFER AGAINST VARIOUS COMMANDS ----- */
            // TALK TO THE HAND
            if (strcmp(buffer, "TALK TO THE HAND") == 0) {
                // execute TALK TO THE HAND
                printf("TALK TO THE HAND\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("WHAT DID I DO WRONG?\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expected output when inputting `TALK TO THE HAND` is just it echoing that, but what I get  is this:

```
TALK TO THE HAND
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
TALK TO THE HAND
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
WHAT DID I DO WRONG?
```

and I have no idea why it seemingly loops over and over again with different outputs.

Comment: In the for loop you copy one character from input to buffer.  You don't initialize buffer ahead of time so the rest of buffer is garbage.  Then you do a string compare, but most likely buffer doesn't even have a '\0' character to terminate it so it will never work until all the characters are copied including the '\0' terminating character.  And the for loop shouldn't be copying input into buffer anyway - just use strcmp with input.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hi, thank you. As you can tell I am REALLY new to C ( but am comfy in Java and Python ). Could you give me some advice on how to properly set up the buffer and copy the /0 char?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/S1K9S8-DU

Comment: `fgets` will insert a null-terminator, but it also includes the newline.  The string you are trying to match against does not have a newline.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a buffer?  Is it to store all the input in one huge string?  Java and C are the same algorithmically so however you would think in Java will be the same with different library functions.  For example, you are looping through the input and copying the bytes but you would never do that in Java so you probably wouldn't do that in C.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Theoretically I want to add multiple commands at a time a la a real shell, so that was me prepping for that -> my guesstimate and how syntax parsing works was to use a buffer and constantly compare the content to possible commands and then chain them after

Comment: Ahh, so you want to read a line of input that might have multiple commands and then add characters one at a time from the input to a buffer until you find a command and then do something with the command and then continue adding more characters from input looking for a subsequent command.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: Ok, before I answer I want to know if this is what you were looking for or whether I misunderstood....  Here is one with a separate input array that gets parsed before adding it to the buffer: https://onlinegdb.com/BJM4iubP8  And here is one where you read directly into the buffer: https://onlinegdb.com/SJcYiO-D8  The advantage of the second is, what if your command really is longer than 20 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a function that returning length of char-array. This is the keyword that returning a count of bytes which needed to allocation into memory any types and structures. Use `strlen` instead.

Try to print `sizeof(char)` and you will understand

Answer (score 2):

**Code iterates too far**

Iterate to the length of the string, not the size of the buffer.

```
    // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++) {
    for(int i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
```

In any case, this iteration is not needed.  Just compare to `input`

```
//if (strcmp(buffer, "TALK TO THE HAND") == 0) {
if (strcmp(input, "TALK TO THE HAND") == 0) {
```

If code wants to copy a *string*:

```
strcpy(buffer, input);
```

Be certain `buffer` is adequate in size.

**Compares not accounting for `'\n'` that was read.**

Lop off potential `'\n`'

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
// add
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
```

**Buffer too small**

`buffer[]` needs to hold 20 characters, `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

```
// char input[20];
char input[20 + 1 + 1];
```

---

**Advanced**

`fgets()` could return `NULL` which indicates `stdin` is closed.

User may enter too much text, good to detect that

```
#define INPUT_N 20
//                extra  \n  \0
char input[INPUT_N + 1 + 1 + 1]; // I'd just go with INPUT_N*2

if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Input closed\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

size_t len = strlen(input);
if (len > 0 && input[len-1] == '\n') {
  input[--len] = '\0';  // lop off \n
}

if (len > INPUT_N) {
  // exit or otherwise cope with too much data
  fprintf(stderr, "Excessive long input\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

...
```